# ¿Como Subir De un Directorio De Android A Google Drive?

Tags: android, google-drive

Estos días he tenido un inconveniente es el siguiente: quiero enviar un archivo que se encuentra en una ruta  de la tarjeta SD, pero no se como lograrlo. Saben por favor ayuda.

Comment: Es la misma Jose? http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33391/como-subir-un-archivo-que-encuentra-en-un-directorio-a-google-drive

Comment: Hay lo siento yo pensando que no la había publicado. Recomiendame la elimino o la dejo.

Comment: Si la dejas probablemente la eliminaran, esoge  la que desees. @( ͡ ͜  ͡  )@

Comment: Y sé más explícito, cuéntano más y muestra el código que has intentado, nadie va a darte la solución entera, podemos ayudarte sobre lo que ya tienes

Comment: Es que no tengo porque no se si es posible muchas gracias.